# gdb: examine stack and little endian clarification

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, stack, stack-overflow

I am studying about the memory layout of a program. I am using gdb to examine the stack in a little endian (intel x86_64) Linux (32 bit) machine. However, I am not able to understand the concept of big-endian and little-endian w.r.t this processor and gdb.

My sample program is:

```
1   #include<stdio.h>
2   
3   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
4       int a = 5;
5       char b[] = "ABCDEFGH";
6   
7       return 0;
8   }

                       [Code - 1]
```

The following sequence of instructions were executed in gdb.

```
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048434: file args.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff4f4) at args.c:7
7       return 0;

(gdb) x/20xw $esp
0xbffff410: 0x0011e0c0  0x08049ff4  0xbffff448  0xbffff4f4
0xbffff420: 0x00284324  0x00283ff4  0x08048470  0x00000005
0xbffff430: 0x4115d4a5  0x45444342  0x00484746  0x6a078d00
0xbffff440: 0x08048470  0x00000000  0xbffff4c8  0x00144bd6
0xbffff450: 0x00000002  0xbffff4f4  0xbffff500  0xb7fff858


                            [Code - 2]
```

Initially, I was confused whether the memory address `0xbffff430` in the stack above contains the value `0x41` or `0xa5`. So I examined the stack starting from the address `0xbffff433`.

```
(gdb) x/8xw 0xbffff433
0xbffff433: 0x44434241  0x48474645  0x078d0000  0x0484706a
0xbffff443: 0x00000008  0xfff4c800  0x144bd6bf  0x00000200

                             [code - 3]
```

As evident from the output above, the address  `0xbffff433` contains the value `0x41`. Thus, the address `0xbffff430` contains the value `0xa5`. Thus we can conclude that memory addresses in gcc are displayed in the following order:-

```
0xbffff433: [0xbffff436][0xbffff435][0xbffff434][0xbffff433]  [0xbffff43a] [0xbffff439][0xbffff438][0xbffff437]
                D           C          B           A             H              G              F          E
```

However, since intel x86_64 is little-endian, from what I understand the order in which the character array is stored (MSB at smallest address) should be as follows:-

```
0xbffff433: [0xbffff436][0xbffff435][0xbffff434][0xbffff433]  [0xbffff43a][0xbffff439][0xbffff438][0xbffff437]
                 A           B         C           D             E           F           G           H
```

Q (a): Could some please explain where am I getting wrong?

Q (b): Furthermore, from `[code 2]` above we can see that the value for variable `a` is stored at the address `0xbffff42c`. The value for variable `a` is: `0x00000005`. Here also LSB is stored at the smallest memory address.

Q (c): However, the problem from Q (a) and (b) doesn't manifest when addresses are stored. For example, from `code - 4` below we can check that at the address `0xbffff448` EBP (`0xbffff4c8`) is stored

```
(gdb) x/4xw $ebp
0xbffff448: 0xbffff4c8  0x00144bd6  0x00000002  0xbffff4f4
```

It is clearly visible that the address is stored in the following order:-

```
0xbffff448: [0xbffff44b][0xbffff44a][0xbffff449][0xbffff448]
                0xbf        0xff        0xf4        0xc8
```

Note: 1) I tried the above code on a VM of ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386. I confirmed the endianness of my machine using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
   unsigned int i = 1;
   char *c = (char*)&i;
   if (*c)    
       printf("Little endian");
   else
       printf("Big endian");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

2) I checked the following thread too [Is GDB interpreting the memory address correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502179/is-gdb-interpreting-the-memory-address-correctly) but I am still not able to understand the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: The char type in C on the x86 is 1 byte long. There is no endianness to take into account. Arrays in C on the x86 go from low addresses to higher addresses. Use `x/9xb b` or `x/9cb b` to see the first 9 elements of the char array b. The `w` in `x/xw` means "print 4-byte words".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: A good question, I don't understand the answer quite well. Could you please give more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The char type in C on the x86 is 1 8-bit byte long, with an alignment of 1 byte; there is no endianness to take into account. Arrays in C on the x86 go from lower addresses to higher addresses. The `w` in `x/xw` means "print 4-byte words", which is fine for showing 32-bit integers and (on 32-bit systems) pointers, but not so great for chars or char arrays. Use `x/9xb b` or `x/9cb b` to see the first 9 elements of the char array `b`, displayed as bytes.